# Duplicated mapping for entity java spring boot JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my project I need to access and save properties form order ( bridge table of customer and product) so I decided to create my custom bridge and use @OneToMany and @ManyToOne instead of using @ManyToMany. However with join column and column that I create to receive productId and customerId to save to database is mapped to the same column it's causing multiple mapped column error how can I save an object to database and still join these tables. should I use @ManyToMany ?

Order class :

```
@Column(name = "customer_id")
private int customerId;
@Column(name = "product_id")
private int productId;
 
Rest of attributes ...
 
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
 
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;`
```

Customer class :

```
Rest of attributes ...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
private List<Order> orders;
```

error : Column 'customer_id' is duplicated in mapping for entity (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)

Ps. I assign customer_id and product_id in table orders to be fk

I try to use @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false) that IntelliJ said

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id",insertable=false,updatable = false)
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id",insertable=false,updatable = false)
    private Customer customer;
```

but it doesn't work and facing error like this
error : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`stockdb`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`))

I create entity and try to save it from CommandLineRunner like this :

```
@Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(CustomerService customerService, OrderService orderService, ProductService productService) {
        return runner -> {
            saveCustomer(customerService);
            saveOrder(orderService,customerService,productService);
        };
    }

    private void saveOrder(OrderService orderService, CustomerService customerService, ProductService productService) {
        orderService.saveOrder(new Order(2,1,200,100,"home",LocalDateTime.now()));
    }

    private void saveCustomer(CustomerService customerService) {
        customerService.saveCustomer(new Customer("name","0000000000"));
    }


}
```

Comment: The first problem in your question is caused because you have a duplicate mapping of both `cusotmer_id` and `product_id` in the `Order` entity. You use those columns for both mapping the ID directly, and as a reference column. This can lead to conflicts (for example, what should Hibernate do if your `customerId` is `1`, but your `customer` refers to a customer with ID `2`?). So that's why you need to mark one of the two as "readonly" so there is one source of truth. That"s what happens if you add `insertable = false`  and `updatable = false`.

Comment: For your last paragraph, there isn't enough information in the question to solve that. Please edit your question to show an example of how you use the `insertable` and `updatable` parameter and how you are creating your entity. Because normally, this should work.

Comment: Sorry for unclear information. I've already adding how I use insertable and updatable and how I create entity.